# My app folder created is not Visible both in Internal Or SD memory

Tags: android, directory

I am new to Android and building an app that needs to save the data into a text file. I wanted to have my app folder created under Internal Storage (/storage/emulated/0/) just exactly same as for WhatsApp. I know the solution about how to FILE create to make directory. My debug console also shows the directory was created but I couldn't see either through Filemanager Or if connected to PC through USB. It is the same case when I try to save in sdcard path. My phone is not Rooted (though tried but not successful). If only possible with rooting the phone, my question is how can I see the WhatsApp folder both in Internal Storage though my phone is not rooted. I wanted to see my folder to be visible same as how I can see WhatsApp folder.

Here is my code and attaching screenshot connected USB to PC:

```
  File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File mydirectory=new File(root + "/Test");
        if (root.canWrite()) {
            if(!mydirectory.exists()) {
                mydirectory.mkdirs(); //directory is created;
                Log.d("created the directory",mydirectory.toString()+"");
            }

            mydirectory.setExecutable(true);
            mydirectory.setReadable(true);
            mydirectory.setWritable(true);


            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[] {mydirectory.toString()}, null, null);

            Intent mediaScannerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            Uri fileContentUri = Uri.fromFile(mydirectory); 
            mediaScannerIntent.setData(fileContentUri);
            getContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScannerIntent); 
        }


AndroidManifest File:


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Version details-
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.saisureshc.gridlayouttest"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

---

Debug Console:

D/created the directory: /storage/emulated/0/Test

---

[image]

[image]

Attaching the screen shot after adding the code as per "user7486817"

But I see folder created doesnt look like a folder

Answer (score 2):

You have `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE`, but you need `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to write to external storage

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the input. I included Write permission for external storage as mentioned. I see a file created but it is not of folder type. I cant see it as a folder. Let me add the screen shot of it at the main post

Comment: mkdir and mkdirs are different, mkdirs should work but try mkdir.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried with both mkdir() and  mkdirs() but still the same. Attached the screen shot

Comment: new File(root + "/Test/")
Add another / and reply with results

Comment: I tried it with end slash with both mkdir() and mkdirs(). Unfortunately still the same.

Comment: File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/testt/");
  file.mkdir();

Comment: Successfully created the folder. Sorry variable name should b folder

Comment: You are missing toString();

Comment: Or you can use new File(root, "test");

Without any slashes

Comment: Thanks. I love to do chat and comfortable too but it is now allowing me to initiate the chats says that I "have only 11 reputations, not enough to chat". I tried with your suggestions still the same. I tried with .toString() and also simply out new File(root, "test"); Without any slashes but still the same

Comment: Have u deleted the file first before running the code again?

Comment: Yes I delete file manually each time. I have cleaned & rebuild the project multiple times. I also tried with .getAbsolutePath but still didn't work. Somehow code is still treating it as a file not considering as a directory. String rootPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test/"; did n't work

Comment: I tried by unclearing cache and set the break points & checked the boolean result of mkdir()/mkdirs(), It is giving result as true but still creates the file but not folder